# In Magento, is there a way to remove attribute from configurable product after already created?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, attributes

In Magento, I have have a bunch of configurable products already created and now have a client that has changed their mind and wants to remove one of the attributes.  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this b/c I keep getting an error message saying:

> This attribute is used in configurable
>   products. You cannot remove it from
>   the attribute set.

I have tried going into the attribute and changing **Use to Create Configurable Product** from "yes" to "no", but that didn't seem to do anything when trying to remove attribute from existing products

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To remove one *super product attribute* (as they are called) from all configurable products, you could execute this SQL query in the database:

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_super_attribute
WHERE attribute_id = <id>
```

The table `catalog_product_super_attribute` links products to super product attributes. You can add and remove attributes to created configurable products there.

Comment: i also want to add that i checked into if deleting an attribute after using this method to be able to, cleans up all its associated records like what products had that attribute set to or not , it does :)

Comment: Worked on Magento 1.9.0.1

Comment: Great answer but be careful because this will delete the attribute from all of your configurable products. You probably already know this because it is what was requested. Additionally, to find the attribute ID you can do `SELECT product_super_attribute_id FROM catalog_product_super_attribute_label WHERE value = 'your attribute name';`

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're trying to remove the attribute from the attribute set first, but you need to remove it from the configurable products, then the attribute set.  Open each configurable product, go to the Associated Products tab and remove the attribute (and linked products) that is not required.  Save each product and then try removing the attribute from the set.

Comment: That should be hard if we have huge no. of products.. Is there any shortcut method? i think we should look for the tables to modify in bulk.. If i'm able to find one, i'll post that

Comment: How do I "remove the attribute" when I'm on the Associated Products tab?  I know I can drag and drop the order of the configurable attributes.  I'm a little lost how I can remove the attribute?  do you mean just set the value in the associated products to empty or something else?

Comment: @veilig same question here. I have no idea what he was talking about. Did you he mean from the product's page? But how to remove the attributes from there? Sometimes I feel like I have no idea about Magento (I'm relatively new) or people give some weird answers.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use phpmyadmin and connect to your database. 
Look for the eav_attribute table.
Delete the attribute you want.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Christian Davén's answer, you could use the following to delete based on the `attribute_code` name instead of the `attribute_id` itself, just to be sure that you are referencing the right ID:

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_super_attribute`
WHERE `attribute_id` IN (
    SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute`
    WHERE `attribute_code` = "attribute"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this could help:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/6059/#t327478

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible from the standard Magento backend.
As such, you have to look at SQL solutions (I'm not familair with these).